# i3 status bar with ANSI *input*

Tags: linux, terminal, x11, i3, ansi

I want to show a text having ANSI escape sequences in a status bar.

The status text is generated by third party tools, that manage themselves the ANSI colors (and hyperlinks, albeit these may be left apart). The status bar is to be displayed in the i3 windows manager (Linux).

I saw at least three approaches to solve this problem, but I failed at each of them:

1. Find a status bar that renders the ANSI colors in its *input*.
2. Find a way to convert ANSI colors to whatever markup language the status bar uses.
3. Display a terminal window as status bar.

## ANSI input

I searched for status bars around i3 and found many (i3status, dzen2, xmobar, polybar, lemonbar, i3cat, conky, barmaid, sbar, yabar).

To the extent of my understanding, none of them allow any formating in a text input, apart from conky *in text mode* (which does not support unicode and crashes regularly).

dwm seems to mention some patch allowing ANSI input related to a status bar, but I failed understanding how to build them up.

## ANSI to markup

Reading the docs, all of the status bar I found define their own markup language at the configuration level. <sup>(I confess I find that a bit weird, why not use the ubiquitous HTML? Just a subset of it would already allow for leveraging powerful tools, like pandoc. Plus, there are tools to convert ANSI colors to HTML spans with a color tag.)</sup>

All of them see input as text (or numerical values) waiting to be formatted at the configuration step. In my case, the tool(s) generating the input is deciding itself whether to show (or not) information, and how to color it. Implementing the complex features it provides in the status bar itself would be cumbersome.

Because they use their own markup language, I found no existing tool able to convert into it. Because it is at the configuration level and not the input, it seems complicated to setup such a pipeline.

## Terminal as bar

This may be the most promising approach.

It is very easy to call a command every second, thanks to `watch --no-wrap --no-title --colors <mycmd>`, providing the "status update" feature.

Technically, it seems feasible to play with *xdotool* to make a X11 terminal window behave as a status bar, as mentioned in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/694537), but I failed to make it work under i3.

Edit: **How to show a text having ANSI escape colors in an i3 status bar (with one or the other method)?**

Comment: Hi, what exactly is the question here?

Comment: How to show a text having ANSI escape colors in an i3 status bar?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using the third method. It transform a terminal window in a dock by setting the X11 properties understood by i3. It does only work with terminal emulator that does NOT fork their sessions from a common process. It also does not support multiple monitors.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: ./dock.sh <command>

height="20" # Expects a single line status, you may edit this to fit your own terminal configuration.

# Cannot use terminal emulator reusing a common daemon from which to fork windows, or else the PID will change.
# e.g. gnome-terminal, terminator, etc.
# urxvt gets X11 errors and shorten the output...
# xterm works just fine.
xterm -bg black -e watch --no-title --color --no-wrap --interval 1 $@ &
PID="$!"
ID=$(xdotool search --sync -pid $PID 2>/dev/null)
width=$(xrandr -q | head -n1 | awk '{print $8}')
xdotool windowunmap --sync ${ID}
xdotool windowsize --sync ${ID} ${width} ${height}
xprop -id "${ID}" -format _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE 32a -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK"
xprop -id "${ID}" -format _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL 32cccccccccccc -set _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL "0,0,${height},0,0,0,0,0,0,${width},0,0"
xdotool windowmap ${ID}
```